# Improve Smartphone GPS with external RTK - will a simple antenna work?

Tags: gps, rtklib

Regarding RTK technique, if you have appropriate equipment for full RTK you will have up to cm accuracy. I wondered if we can use very simple external to device antenna (**I'm not** speaking about Garmin GPS device style build in antennas like we all had in past mobile phones) communicating with the smartphone via wifi/bluetooth/rfid + software layer running on the smartphone, to somehow take advantage on RTK technique in order to improve current GPS accuracy which is ~3 meters to let's say even something like ~1 meter?

Will we compromise accuracy by using very primitive external hardware - So is a simple antenna relevant for RTK?

Speaking about [this article](http://hackaday.com/2013/08/05/centimeter-level-precision-gps-for-500)

So they said "one base station and one on a vehicle, connected via radio link" but not explaining + $900 is too much. The question is very simple: Can we have the equivalent to "base station" as the smartphone, and equivalent to "one on a vehicle" as simple piece of metal-e.g. antena, all together costs nothing comparing to smartphone price, in order to get 1 meter accuracy compromising the 1 cm accuracy because still we modified here cheaper constellation?

Comment: It boils down to the GPS Chipset being used. https://communityhealthmaps.nlm.nih.gov/2014/07/07/how-accurate-is-the-gps-on-my-smart-phone-part-2/

Comment: @Mapperz thanks can you please explain?

Comment: It is discussed here http://hackaday.com/2013/08/05/centimeter-level-precision-gps-for-500/

Comment: @Mapperz They said "one base station and one on a vehicle, connected via radio link" but not explaining + $900 is too much. The question is very simple: Can we have the equivalent to "base station" as the smartphone, and equivalent to "one on a vehicle" as simple piece of metal-e.g. antena, all together costs nothing comparing to smartphone price, in order to get 1 meter accuracy compromising the 1 cm accuracy because still we modified here cheaper constellation?

Comment: In short, a base and rover GNSS system is going to be considerably more than $900. Think in the $20k+ range even on the low end. In order to get 1 meter accuracy you would not need a base and rover type configuration....you need a GNSS device capable of receiving SBAS or DGNSS corrections. It would also need the software or capability to connect to your smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

No, it takes more than an antenna to make the GPS chipset provide the satellite and pseudorange information that high accuracy RTK requires.  The cheaper chipsets in cell phones do a position solution internally and report only the results. To do the RTK solution, you need either the raw data out of the phone to recalculate the solutions, or you need a chip in the phone capable of accepting external information.